# Trying to display caption inside div containing an image

Tags: css

I have a div which contains an image with some CSS transitions.
I am trying to make a caption inside this div to be shown at the bottom, on top of the contained image. It is important that I need the caption to display inside and not outside of the box.

Here is what I have:

```
.t_box {
        width: 250px;
        height: 155px;
        background-color: #ccc;
        border: 5px solid #FF0000;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 40;  
        overflow:hidden;

}
.t_box img {
        max-width: 100%;
        opacity: 0.6;
        transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.t_box img:hover {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
        /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
        /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: scale(1.3);
}
.t_caption {
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: #666;
        color: #fff;
        z-index: 50;

        position: absolute;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="t_box">
    <img src="image.jpg" />
    <div class="t_caption">This is a caption</div>
</div>
```

Here is a link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/seenvvty/

Comment: add bottom 0 to `.t_caption`.

Comment: Is this what you're after http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/q81rrdwf/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `bottom:0;` in `t_caption` css:

```
.t_caption {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #666;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 50;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seenvvty/1/)